# Get full tag / line number from net/html

Tags: go

After parsing a document using `html.Parse(r io.Reader)` we get a node tree. Each DOM node provides it's surroundings, the name of the tag and that tag's attributes. [See here](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Node).

What's the best way to go from a node object to the string text of that node in the file `r`, as well as the line number of that tag within that file?

Answer (score 0):

The html package does not record that information, so it is not available.

Comment: Right, I'm aware of that. What I'm asking is what is the best way to work around this. Can we extend the html package or do we need to fork it and add that functionality. Is it possible by writing our own tokeniser?

Comment: It would be necessary to fork it and add the position information to both Token and Node, and then everywhere a Node is created, copy the position information from the associated Token, if any.